# How do I calculate width of div based on previous child width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So let's say have the following content structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contentOne" style="width:50px"></div>
    <div class="contentTwo"></div>
    <div class="contentThree"></div>
    <div class="contentFour"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve on page load, is for the width of the 1st div (contentOne) to be picked  up and increment the width of the other 3 divs by 50px. In the end I want the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contentOne" style="width:50px"></div>
    <div class="contentTwo" style="width:100px"></div>
    <div class="contentThree" style="width:150px"></div>
    <div class="contentFour" style="width:200px"></div>
</div>
```

First prize would be for this to be possibly using CSS3 Calc. If not JS will be a close 1st princess.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, CSS has no preceding-sibling selector (although there is a "following sibling" selector, for some reason), so a pure CSS solution isn't yet possible. jQuery would be something like this:

```
$('div:not(:first)').each(function()
{
    $(this).width($(this).prev().width() + 50);
});
```

Comment: Simple, yes effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery to this . The code would be something like this. Please make the changes appropriate this is just a demo code.

```
    var widthOfFirstChild=$('.wrapper').eq(1).width();
    $('.width div').each(
    function(){
    $(this).attr('style':widthOfFirstChild+50);
    widthOfFirstChild=+50
    });
```